# Spring Boot 2.1 - @WebMvcTest without Spring Security Auto-Configuration

Tags: spring-boot

Before migrating to Spring Boot 2.1, we had a couple of controller tests in our services utilizing `@WebMvcTest` in combination with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`:

```
@WebMvcTest(SomeController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
public class SomeControllerTests { ... }
```

This had the effect that the Spring Security configuration was disabled and you could run MVC tests without mocking OAuth/JWT.

In Spring Boot 2.1, the `secured` attribute is deprecated and the release notes mention that

> [...] @WebMvcTest looks for a WebSecurityConfigurer bean [...].

In order to avoid the deprecated `secured` attribute and loading of our `WebSecurityConfigurer` we rewrote our tests to:

```
@WebMvcTest(
    value = SomeController.class,
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = WebSecurityConfigurer.class),
    excludeAutoConfiguration = MockMvcSecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class SomeControllerTests { ... }
```

The question is: is there a more compact way in Spring Boot 2.1 to define such tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, rather than working around the fact the flag is deprecated, you should embrace the fact that this is going in that direction going forward.

As of Spring Boot 2.1, if you have Spring Security, your tests will be secured using your custom configuration. What is the actual problem with that?

If you don't want to authenticate for certain tests, just use Spring Security's test infrastructure and add `@WithMockUser`.

Comment: Our services run with Spring Security OAuth2. I didn't have a detailed look but I think in that scenario `@WithMockUser` won't help much. But thanks anyway, I wasn't sure we were on the right track.

Comment: The idea of slicing is to enable only what is necessary. So I do not want to embrace activating much more code than I need.

Comment: The idea of slicing is to enable what makes sense for a particular layer of your application. If you disagree with security being enabled for web tests, you can always create your own slice.

Comment: How can I fallback to the previous behavior? I don't want to use the deprecated flag and even if I do controllers that need to inject the principal will require some security configuration, and in order to provide that I'll need to set up my database infrastructure so all the beans can be wired properly.

Comment: The flag has been deprecated because that behaviour is going away. The last part of my answer mentions how to enable a security context in test.

Comment: It's sad that even though the tests won't require database infrastructure given that I mock the services but due to this change this is now required.

Maybe I'll try to create a security configuration for the test that won't rely on this infrastructure and find a way for the production one to be ignored for tests.

Comment: the link between the database and security is unclear. Can you please create another question with your setup as they are too many unknowns at this point. Thanks

Comment: It does not feel right to include security by default for testing web layer. I am not sure if this is the right direction Spring is going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same scenario and what helped was using the below annotations instead of `@WebMvcTest`. In this case, `@WithMockUser` did not help.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@Import({MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ResourceProperties.class, WebMvcProperties.class})
```

Classes that existed in `controllers` / `value` of `@WebMvcTest` goes into `value` of `@Import` annotation.

Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14227#issuecomment-688824627

Comment: what do you do in place of this.mockMvc ie the autowired MockMvc... because its null when you take out the @WebMvcTest?