# JHipster RestController WebMvcTest fails to load

Tags: spring-mvc, jhipster, spring-boot-test

I'm using JHipster 6.2.0 and I want to create a WebMvcTest for a RestController. When I run the test, the application context does not load and I get:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.mytest.security.jwt.TokenProvider' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

I'm using junit5 and spring boot 2.1.7

I tried adding @MockBean TokenProvider tokenProvider, and then the next missing dependency is CorsFilter. Mocked that but then I get a IllegalArgumentException because the mocked CorsFilter does not have a filter name defined. I thought about disabling the security filters, but I would like to keep the test configurations as vanilla as possible, utilizing the WebMvcTest default configurations.

I reproduced the issue with this simple example.

```java
package com.example.mytest.web.rest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/my")
    public MyResponse get() {
        MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();
        myResponse.text = "test";
        return myResponse;
    }

    static class MyResponse {
        String text;
    }

}
```

```java
package com.example.mytest.web.rest;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void get() {
        // doesn't run, due to NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.mytest.security.jwt.TokenProvider' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    }


}
```

I expect that I should be able to run a GET mockMvc test without having to mock a CorsFilter name. This mocking would need to be done in every WebMvcTest and is very repetitive. I don't want to run a full @SpringBootTest for every RestController. All the generated RestController tests are @SpringBootTests and run in a full application context.

Some similar questions:

[Spring Boot 2.1 - @WebMvcTest without Spring Security Auto-Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389774/spring-boot-2-1-webmvctest-without-spring-security-auto-configuration)

[Security configuration on Spring Boot 2.1 - How to keep the default instead of my custom for tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506527/security-configuration-on-spring-boot-2-1-how-to-keep-the-default-instead-of-m)

Comment: Did you include the `spring-security-test` dependency?

Comment: Yes ```spring-security-test``` is on the classpath.

Comment: It looks like you are using Junit 5. Try adding `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` to the `MyControllerTest` class.

Comment: Thanks for helping. ```@WebMvcTest``` is a meta annotation that includes the spring extension definition. The Junit Spring extension runs fine, I think the problem is with the way Jhipster builds it's security configuration. ```@WebMvcTest``` is classpath scanning for security configuration classes, and tries to pull in the default jhipster generated security configuration using Con. But there are no TokenProvider or CorsFilter beans defined. So the application context fails to load.

Comment: Ok, last idea I have ;-) Add `@ContextConfiguration` and specify the beans and configurations you need.